# Javamail Fetch Emails from specific month

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

Im trying and succeeding fetching emails via IMAP from Exchange server.
My purpose is to copy(DUPLICATE) emails from "INBOX" to a specific folder by Date.
E.g. Duplicate all JANUARY EMAILS from inbox folder to "JANUARY" folder. etc.

I have done this, and its works! However, it doesnt find all January emails. i have seen many emails which where not duplicated to the destination folder.

Do you guys have a better solution than this?

```
   `Calendar cal1 = null;
    cal2.set(2017, 12, 31);
    Calendar cal2 = null;
    cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(2017, 12, 01); // a MONTH BEFORE!!

    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
    d1 = df1.parse("01/01/2018");
    d2 = df1.parse("31/01/2018");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {


                      e1.printStackTrace();

                }


                if (init())

                      ;

                {

    try {
    String credentials = String.format(CREDENTIALS_FORMAT, domain, username1);
    store = session.getStore(MAIL_PROTOCOL);
    for (int i = 0; i < mailboxes.size(); i++) {
    store.connect(host, credentials + mailboxes.get(i), password);
     folderSource = store.getFolder(SourcefolderName);
    folderDest = store.getFolder(DestfolderName);
    folderSource.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
     if (!folderDest.exists()) {
    folderDest.create(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    }
      Date datecal1 = new Date(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
     Date datecal2 = new Dat`enter code here`e(cal2.getTimeInMillis());
    ReceivedDateTerm dateTermCal1 = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, d1);
     ReceivedDateTerm dateTermCal2 = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LE, d2);       SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(dateTermCal2, dateTermCal1);
     Message messages[] = folderSource.search(andTerm);
    folderSource.copyMessages(messages, folderDest);'
```

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  You're at the mercy of what the Exchange server returns for your search query, so if the server doesn't find all the expected messages there's not much you can do other then checking each message in your application.

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for replying.
It seems there are child folders under the INBOX folder.
How can i tell Java mail to include all child folders under the Inbox folder?

Comment: There's no way with IMAP to search more than one folder at a time.  You can use Folder.list to find all the folders and then open each one and search it.

Comment: Hi @BillShannon , I was able to run the code with store.getFolder("Inbox").list();
However there are child folder which below them in the hierarchy there are more folders.
the Code doesnt print them, only the ones that are below the Inbox and orphans.

Im using Java Mail version 1.4.4

Comment: `Folder[] foldArray = store.getFolder("Inbox").list();`

`for (Folder fld : forldArray)`

`System.out.println(fld.getName();`

Comment: You're using a [very old version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/), but that's not the problem.  The list method only returns immediate children.  You either need to recurse down the hierarchy, or use list("*").  Note that the latter can be very expensive on some servers with a large number of mailboxes.

Comment: Hello @BillShannon , by any chance, do you have a list of recursive solution?

Comment: See the [folderlist.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/folderlist.java) sample program.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon . And Sorry for my late response.